# Beginner Resources for Roots Theme Framework

Tags: framework, theme-roots

I'm building a WordPress theme, using Roots as a starter theme. Are there any tutorials telling me how to build a theme off of Roots? I've worked with starter themes before, but this one is a whole new monster. I don't know what I'm supposed to edit, and what I'm not supposed to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roots theme comes with a nice set of Docs https://github.com/retlehs/roots/tree/master/doc
but if you want to make sure you don't overwrite something important or want to keep updating your theme then you should create a child theme.

Comment: I was looking for more of a tutorial, but I don't think any exist. Thanks, though.